# Ruby on Rails, pass Image from one object to another or from NEW to CREATE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I'm pretty new to Ruby on Rails.

I changed this thread, because i recognized that I was searching for my problems' solution at the wrong end.

Here's my Problem:

I got a Class **ProfileProposal** which I upload an Image with(Using CarrierWave).
Now I want to convert **ProfileProposal** to another class, called **Profile**.
So I pass all the Information to the NEW-Form of **Profile**.

Works fine with strings, but not with Images.

**What I've already tried/done:**

Pass the Image as GET Param to the Create Method:

```
<%= form_for @profile, :url => { :action => "create", :controller => "profiles", :image => @profile_proposal.image } do |f| %>

#
```

Which now works, so I DO have the image-url.

What's not working is the following:

```
@profile = Profile.new(params[:profile], :image => new_image_url)
# OR
@profile.image = new_image_url
```

@profile.image still has the default value given by Carrierwave.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed that problem, by using paperclip and creating a new Instance via

```
Profile.create(:name => @profile_proposal.name, :image => @profile_proposal.image)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming from using paperclip, not carrierwave, so I'll try to keep this high level.  But I have an idea for you.  Maybe you can set the filename of the new attachment before it exists, then move the image to that path.  With paperclip this would play out like:

```
@profile.image_file_name = "profile.jpg"
# creates the directory of the new path.  There's probably a better way to do this:
FileUtils.mkdir_p @profile.image_file_path.gsub(/[^\/]*$/,'')
FileUtils.mv @profile_proposal.image_path @profile.image_path
```

Comment: Hey, moving the file works fine, also creating the directory does.
What is not working is changing the file name :(

Comment: hey, I changed my question, hope you guys can help me out

Answer (score 0):

You should embed a hidden field in that `Profile` form, referencing `ProfileProposal` by some ID. Then while handling the form server side, after everything is validated and ready for save, you should copy the image using some read/write methods, from `ProfileProposal` instance to `Profile` instance. I'm not sure how CarrierWave wants you to do this.

Comment: There is the possibility of more than one proposal for one profile, so:
profile has_many profile_proposals.
I can pass params in the Profile Form, where I still know the image. But in Create I can't set the Image :-/